# Agregar texto desde LinkedList a un JButton en Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Soy algo nuevo en programación, y estoy haciendo un programa que simula un estacionamiento para motos, en el que te da la opción de agregar una matrícula, dar de baja una matrícula y salir del programa.

Hay 4 botones que simulan los lugares desocupados del estacionamiento, y cada vez que agregar una matrícula nueva, uno de los botones cambia de color a rojo, y cuando se da de baja alguna matrícula, estos regresan de color verde.

El problema es el siguiente, necesito que la matrícula que se ingresó, aparezca como texto dentro del botón, pero no logro hacer que mi programa imprima dentro de los botones, entonces solo estoy imprimiendo las matrículas en un Label, ¿alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para que las matrículas se impriman dentro de los botones? Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida y gracias.

```
public class InterfazMotos extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    
    public InterfazMotos() {
        initComponents();
       
        pnlRegistrar.setVisible(false);
        pnlBaja.setVisible(false);    
        btnLugar1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        btnLugar2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        btnLugar3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        btnLugar4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
          
        
    }

    LinkedList <String> lista = new LinkedList<>();
    int limite = Integer.valueOf(4); 


    private void cambioColor(String matricula) //Método para el cambio de colores
    {
        
        int tamaño = lista.size();
        int restaColor = limite - lista.size();        
        
         switch(tamaño)
                   {
                        case 0:                           
                            break;
                        case 1: 
                            btnLugar1.setBackground(Color.red);                            
                            break;
                        case 2: 
                            btnLugar2.setBackground(Color.red);                          
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            btnLugar3.setBackground(Color.red);                           
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            btnLugar4.setBackground(Color.red); 
                            break;
                   }    
         
                    switch (restaColor)
                    {
                        case 0:                           
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            btnLugar4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            btnLugar3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            btnLugar2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            btnLugar1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                    }
         
    }

    private void registro(){ //Método para registrar matrículas, junto con condiciones para cuando se acabaron los espacios disponibles o se repitió una matrícula
        
        String matricula = txtPlacaR.getText();    
        boolean validar = true;
        
        if(lista.size() == limite)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Estacionamiento lleno");
            validar = false;
        }   
        
                if (lista.isEmpty())
        {
           lista.add(matricula);                
           btnLugar1.setBackground(Color.red);
           bb.setText("Matrículas registradas: " + lista.toString());           
        }            
        
        else
        {                        
            for(int i = 0; i != lista.size(); i++)
            {                         
                if(lista.get(i).equals(matricula))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Placas Existentes");
                    validar = false;
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            
            while(validar == true)
            {
                lista.add(matricula);
                bb.setText("Matrículas registradas: " + lista.toString());
                for(int i = 0; i != limite; i++)
                {
                   cambioColor(matricula);
                   validar = false;
                }                
            }          

        }
                
    }
    
    
    private void baja() //Método para dar de baja una matrícula
   {
        String matriculaBaja = txtPlacaB.getText();                      
        
        if(lista.isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Estacionamiento Vacío");                
        } 
        else         
        {
            lista.remove(matriculaBaja);
            bb.setText("Matrículas registradas: " + lista.toString());
            cambioColor(matriculaBaja);            
        }     
    }

    
    private void btnSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void btnRegistrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    pnlRegistrar.setVisible(true);
    }                                            

    private void btnRegistroMotoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        registro();
        txtPlacaR.setText("");
        txtPropietario.setText("");
        pnlRegistrar.setVisible(false);
    }                                               

    private void btnBajaMotoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
     baja();
     txtPlacaB.setText("");
     pnlBaja.setVisible(false);
    }                                           

    private void btnBajaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    pnlBaja.setVisible(true);
    }
```

[image: Imagen de la interfaz del programa]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para setear un text en un button se usa el atributo **Text** Ejemplo:  button.setText("").

Por lo tanto.

```
   switch(tamaño)
                   {
                        case 0:                           
                            break;
                        case 1: 
                            btnLugar1.setBackground(Color.red); 
                            btnLugar1.setText(lista.get(0));
                            break;
                        case 2: 
                            btnLugar2.setBackground(Color.red);
                            btnLugar1.setText(lista.get(1));                         
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            btnLugar3.setBackground(Color.red);
                            btnLugar1.setText(lista.get(2));                           
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            btnLugar4.setBackground(Color.red); 
                            btnLugar1.setText(lista.get(3));
                            break;
                   }    

        switch (restaColor)
                    {
                        case 0:                           
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            btnLugar4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            btnLugar1.setText("Disponible lugar 1");                           
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            btnLugar3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            btnLugar1.setText("Disponible lugar 2");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            btnLugar2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            btnLugar1.setText("Disponible lugar 3");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            btnLugar1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            btnLugar1.setText("Disponible lugar 4");
                            break;
                    }
```

Saudos.